# Paypal Subscription price shows zero

Tags: php, paypal

I have the following form code in my website however when I click on the Paypal subscription button the price of the subscription shows $0.00 on the paypal checkout page. Is there something wrong with my form parameters?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="registrations-facilitator@invent2win.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.55"> <!--Cost-->
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="1"> <!--Monthly subscription-->
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="M"> <!--Monthly subscription-->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!--YES, make it reoccurring-->
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Economy Sandbox">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="$usernum" />  
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/purchasecomplete&email=$email?num=$usernum" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="http://www.example.com/cancel" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/purchasecomplete&email=$email?num=$usernum">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: You have exchanged the value for p3 and t3 . You have to exchange it to make it work . ie , p3=1 and t3=M

Comment: You are correct. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="registrations-facilitator@invent2win.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.55">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Economy Sandbox">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="4" />  
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/purchasecomplete&email=$email?num=$usernum" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"  value="http://www.example.com/cancel" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.example.com/purchasecomplete&email=$email?num=$usernum">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: This answer will be more useful to readers if could give an explanation!